# Annotations testing issue

Tags: testng

Testing When I provide `@dataprovider` class inside `@test`, it is throwing 'cannot be resolved into a type' error. Anybody knows how to resolve this?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Data provider class is in different package. So that, it should be imported before using it. Please add import statement before using it.

```
import DataProvider.Dp_Mercury;
```